# set colors in android

Tags: android, background, tablerow

I'm trying to set the background color for a tablerow in android and am having trouble referencing the proper int. Below is the code. Am I doing something wrong? The color that turns up in the background is a light grey.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Trackfolio</string>
    <color name="colorWhite">#FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="colorBlack">#000000</color>
    <color name="colorLightBlue">#6495ED</color>
</resources>

row.setBackgroundColor(R.color.colorLightBlue);
```

Also is there a way to set the text color?

```
tv.setTextColor(R.color.colorBlack);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cfarm54,

The way you are accessing the colors you are getting the offset location in R.java gen file.

You need to access them like this...

```
Resources res = context.getResources();
row.setBackgroundColor(res.getColor(R.color.high_priority));
```

Answer (score 0):

Oops: dumb me, you should use tableRow.setBackgroundResource() when referecing a color resource.

Answer (score 0):

Try `setBackgroundResource(int color)`. Using `setBackgroundColor` uses the int that R.color.colorLightBlue uses to reference your defined color, and tries to parse it as a color, rather than retrieving the referenced color.

Comment: Looks like @willytate's method should work. Just use `setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorLightBlue));` /untested